# Link to a page in HTML and immediately call a specific Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML files like this:

```
file1.html:
<a href="file2.html" onclick="showSection(1)">section 1 of file2</a>
<a href="file2.html" onclick="showSection(2)">section 2 of file2</a>

file2.html:
<script>
  function showSection(sectionId) {
    section = document.getElementById(sectionId);
    section.style.display = "block";
  }  
</script>
<style>
  section { display: none; }
</style>
...
<section id="1">
  Section 1
</section>
<section id="2">
  Section 2
</section>
```

On clicking one of link in file1, I would like to immediately call a Javascript function that only shows section 1 or 2, depending on which link was closed. How can I do this? The issue with the above code is that it calls a function which is not defined in file1.html

Comment: Are you looking for the `onclick` function?

Comment: Let us see the function / attempts you've made to get this to happen.

Comment: Before anything else, you should extend the hrefs a little, f.e. with "#1" and "#2", respectively.

Comment: I added an attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can not call functions in other frames, except for specific APIs like `window.postMessage()`. But this ist not what you want, I think.
if you want to execute a function when the page loads you can simply execute it in a `<script>` tag, or listen to the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which will fire when the document has been constructed.